# What video editors have a similar feature (Storyboard) to Windows Movie Maker?

Tags: video-editor, editing, youtube, windows-movie-maker, intermediate

I used to use Windows Movie Maker when I was growing up and I really enjoyed using it. I have since moved on to free, nonlinear editors like ShotCut and PowerDirector. There was however one feature that I really enjoyed using in Movie Maker. That feature was the "Storyboard" feature on Movie Maker.

The "Storyboard" feature was a feature that allowed us to reorder the clips that were being used. It is different from the timeline feature where you trim your clip or modify the timing. I know I am essentially describing Movie Maker but I really like that feature and I want to focus on the clips I use. Does anyone know of an editor that have this feature? Or where can I ind this feature in the editors I use?